# How to search in elassandra within a frozen of map?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elasticsearch-5, elassandra

I am using elassandra version 6.2.3.4

And I have a cassandra table structure like below : -

```
CREATE TABLE trackfleet_db.eventsgroup (
imei text,
week int,
event text,
startevent timestamp,
oevent text,
ostartevent timestamp,
duration double,
endevent timestamp,
eventdt timestamp,
eventstats map<text, frozen<eventstartend>>,
lat text,
long text,
odo int,
oduration double,
oendevent timestamp,
olat text,
olong text,
oodo int,
opreviouslat text,
opreviouslong text,
ostate int,
previouslat text,
previouslong text,
state int,
status int,
PRIMARY KEY ((imei, week, event), startevent, oevent, ostartevent)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (startevent ASC, oevent ASC, ostartevent ASC)
```

And in "eventstats map>" field I am inserting following data : -

```
eventstats = {'ExB': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'InB': {start: 6, end: 6}, 'd1': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd10': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd11': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd12': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd13': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd14': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd15': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd16': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd17': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd18': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd19': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd2': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd20': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd3': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd4': {start: 2, end: 2}, 'd5': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd6': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd7': {start: 0, end: 0}, 'd8': {start: 1, end: 1}, 'd9': {start: 0, end: 0}}
```

Now I want to perform a search in Elasticsearch on eventstats field like below :

```
eventstats.ExB.start='0'
```

Then it is returning 0 docs.

So how should I perform search on the fields of "eventstats" in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

As of Elassandra v6.2.3.4, UDT inside map is not supported.

It's planned to be supported in a future release.